# Laravel Autenticação Vários Tipos de Usuários Diferentes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Preciso de uma orientação de direção em como eu vou separar as minhas autenticações por tipo de usuário...

Minha aplicação tem 3 tipos de usuários, cada um com o seu dashboard e painel admin específico, adminGeral(eu), empresas e consumidores.

Deixo todo mundo na mesma tabela de usuário e relaciono ele com as minhas 3 entidades, ou crio uma autenticação separada para cada?

Quais seriam as possibilidades? E quais seriam as vantagens e desvantagens de cada uma?

Comment: Acho que tu deveria usar roles e permissions, recomento usar [esse package https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust ](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)

Answer (score 1):

O Laravel já possui o que é preciso para múltiplas autenticação a partir da versão 5.2.
Veja esse vídeo bem simples que explica em detalhes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuUX3NHsGag

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Podes colocar aqui na resposta partes importantes desse video? Assim a resposta fica mais útil para outros que tenham o mesmo problema e não depende só do link.

Answer (score 1):

Eu trabalho com tabelas diferentes uma para cada tipo.
Se for o laravel 5.1 tem esse pacote muito bom
[kbwebs/multiauth](https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth)

No 5.2 já da para fazer essas múltiplas autenticações.